# incompatible types: Predicate<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Predicate<? super CAP#2>

Tags: java-8, java-stream, predicate

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class StreamMethod{
    public static void main(String... args){
        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));

        allMatch(data, x -> x < 10);
    }

    public static <T> void allMatch(List<?> list, Predicate<? super T> predicate){
        boolean allSatisfy = list.stream().allMatch(predicate);
        System.out.println(allSatisfy);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `incompatible types: Predicate<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Predicate<? super CAP#2>` . Can you help me to solve it? and why it is showing this error?

Then I also change the above lines of passing arguments as

```
Predicate<Integer> pred= x -> x < 10;
allMatch(data, pred);
```

But still facing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to `List<T> list` instead of `List<?> list`

Comment: Can you explain it please?

Comment: @UnKnown The problem with using the wildcard `?` for the list of values is that the compiler doesn't know which type the elements are inside your `allMatch` method. While the `Predicate` is for `T`s, the list could contain anything: `T`s, `Object`s, `Banana`s, `Minion`s... And the error is telling you that the `Predicate` cannot be used to filter those values. By using `List<T>` you show the compiler that all the elements will be `T`s, and the `Predicate` can filter those.